# Creating an array within a method

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have:

```
class account {
    private function something() {
#       TRYING TO PUT ARRAY HERE
    }
}
```

But, it keeps giving me an error when I use either of these. I googled how to create an array within a class, to no avail.

```
private array options = ['cost' => 20];

array options = ['cost' => 20];
```

How is it done? 
Thanks.

Comment: See how to create array here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some of the fundamentals of PHP. You need to refactor your code as follows:

```
class account
{
    private $options;

    private function something() 
    {
        $options = array();
        $options['cost'] = 20;

        $this->options = $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a property of a method which contains an array. You could declare it like this:

```
class Account
{
    private $options;

    public function setOptions()
    {
        $this->options = array('options' => 20);
    }

}
```

Or you could just set it like this:

```
class Account
{
    private $options = ['cost' => 20]; // set property

    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }
}

$obj = new Account;
$options = $obj->getOptions();
print_r($options);
```